# Delete all rows based on column name MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need to delete or overwrite rows value in a column.
I'm struggling finding a way to do it.

I need something like this.

```
DELETE * FROM schema.table WHERE COLUMN_NAME = nameofthecolumn;
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

edit: i used the query above without * and gave me this error: but i correctly inserted the column name.

```
    DELETE FROM schema.table WHERE COLUMN_NAME = nameofthecolumn; 
    Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'COLUMN_NAME' in 'where clause'
```

Show create table output:

```
'infoselection', 'CREATE TABLE `infoselection` (\n  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `INFOSELECTED` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY 
 (`ID`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

I want to delete all rows in INFOSELECTED.

Comment: Remove the `*`, see docs...  [DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)   (yes, this will delete the complete ROW !!)

Comment: @Luuk i don't know why workbench say: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'COLUMN_NAME' in 'where clause'

Comment: Please give a more detailed description of what you are trying to do. I thought you where trying to delete records from the table `table` with the field `column_name` set to `nameofthecolumn`   (whatever that is....)

Comment: Add info what you have, and what you want to get.   by now it's clear that your SQL-skills need some improvement... 

Comment: @Luuk i updated the question above. Yes, i'm still a junior currentyl working on it.

Comment: Your probleem seems to be: "I need to delete or overwrite rows value in a column".   It would be helpful if we know the name of that table. And the name of the column you want to do something with.  Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <yourtablename>;` to your question, and explain in words what you want to get after the "delete or overwrite"

Comment: @Luuk done updated the question.

Comment: Added a longer explanation as an answer. Hopefully it makes thing, at least a bit, more clear....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `infoselection` (  
   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   `INFOSELECTED` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And you want to delete all rows in `INFOSELECTED`, you might have a language problem.

Let me explain.

1. `INFOSELECTED` is a column. That's why it will be very difficult to delete all rows in `INFOSELECTED`.
2. A row has two fields, `ID`, and `INFOSELECTED`.  Deleting all rows in ... will also delete some (or all) of the `ID` values.

If you want the values from `INFOSELECTED` removed, you could do:

```
UPDATE `infoselection`
SET `INFOSELECTED` = NULL;
```

If you want to completely remove the column `INFOSELECTED`, you might want to do:

```
ALTER TALBE `infoselection`
DROP COLUMN `INFOSELECTED`;
```

After that you will only have 1 column, with the name `ID`.  But you can still have multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table_name SET COLUMN_NAME = ""

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to "delete" value in a column, you actually need to use UPDATE.

```
UPDATE schema.table
SET nameofthecolumn = NULL
WHERE ...
```

DELETE is being used only to remove rows from table

Comment: Thx i got ur example but i need to DELETE not update.